# automated call from skype account via C# application (using Skype4COM.dll)

Tags: c#, asp.net, skype4com

We are trying to place a mobile call via Skype API(Skype4COM.dll) in C# application. We found a sample code in one of the website. The code is as follows.The code is throwing an error at line "**skype.PlaceCall**".

```
Skype skype = new Skype();
if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
{
    // start minimized with no splash screen
    skype.Client.Start(true, true);
}

// wait for the client to be connected and ready
 skype.Attach(skype.Protocol, true);
// skype.Attach(7, true);



var skypeID = "phone no";

var call = skype.PlaceCall(skypeID);
```

There is no specific error message, after executing this line of code, calls move to **cancel state**.

It would be great if you provide us some pointers to overcome this issue.

Thanks
Jonyy

Answer (score 0):

try using following code

```
 Call call = skype.PlaceCall(skypeID);
        do
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        } while (call.Status != TCallStatus.clsInProgress);
        call.StartVideoSend();
```

It will works for once but sucked at trying again. It is a bug of Skype4COM